# react-native-camera: sdk manager plateforms-tools 28.0.1 can't be installed

Tags: react-native, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to install react-native-camera. I'm on Ubuntu 18, Webstorm for IDE. Targeting Android.

For the Android SDK, I don't have a full Android Studio install. I've instead install only android-sdk and I'm using the sdkmanager. That works fine with my stub app, it compile and runs on Android with

```
react-native run-android
```

I've installed react-native-camera as a module with npm as per the [indications](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera#mostly-automatic-install-with-react-native):

```
npm install react-native-camera --save
react-native link react-native-camera
```

So far so good. It links. If I try to launch the app however (even before trying to actually use the camera), I get some warnings:

```
> Configure project :react-native-camera 
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 28.0.1)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
WARNING: platform-tools package is not installed, and automatic installation failed.
```

So I've tried to install the platforms tools using the sdk manager & instructions provided [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager):

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

Which yields:

```
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
```

So I am guessing it really has to do with the sdkmanager...

Do I absolutely need 28.0.1 for react-native-camera? If so, how can I get around this issue with the SDK manager? I've tried various similar syntax for the install of the platform and it didn't work. I checked with sdkmanager --list that it's the proper name (seems to be). And if I go under android-sdk/platforms-tools all I see there is the adb file (or perhaps the install is supposed to just update that file?)

Answer (score 1):

Silly me.

I needed to run the SDK manager as sudo. To do that:

```
sudo bash sdkmanager [installations args as per post above].
```

I will leave the post - I lost a ridiculous amount of time for that, hopefully it can help others....

And yes - if the platform-tools install has worked then under /platform-tools you should see a bunch of files, not just the adb one.